# Using a class data-member in a class function as default value, c++

Tags: c++

In c++ I'm trying to set a class data as default value for a function in the class, but it throws an error while building it.
The code looks like this:

```
    class tree{
    public:
    node *root;
    bool push(node what, node* current = root, int actualheight = 1){
```

The compiler throws the error

> invalid use of non-static data member 'tree::root' from the location of the function

If I remove the default value of 'current' it works fine. What could be the problem? How could I fix it?

Comment: @EdChum, I don't think the intent is to initialize a member, it's a default argument

Comment: @Angew yes you and Jonathan are correct, I misread the function name and thought it was the ctor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `this` pointer in the function parameter list, so you can't refer to class members in default arguments.

The solution is to overload the function:

```
bool push(node what, node* current, int actualheight = 1){...}

bool push(node what){ return push(what, root); }
```

Now when you call `push` with one argument it forwards to the other overload, providing `root` as the second argument, which does exactly what you were trying to achieve.